# Is there an output difference between php 4 and 5?

Tags: php, php4

I noticed the other day that a new script I wrote for php 5 began outputting html that was viewable before the php script had actually finished. Did this happen with 4?

For instance, I have a long loop that echos something out with each iteration. The output was small in terms of kb, so I dont think it was lag due to the download speed. Can someone explain the difference in output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe there a difference in the configuration of the [output_buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) directive, in `php.ini` ?

If `output_buffering` is enabled, PHP will "keep" the generated output in memory *(at least, if it doesn't become bigger than the size of the memory buffer)*, and only send it to the browser when the page's generation is finished.

If `output_buffering` is disabled, the ouput is sent immediatly when generated, even if the script's execution is not finished yet.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt there is a difference to this regard between PHP 4 and 5, but you can get this behaviour on both versions, namely by enabling/disabling the `output_buffer`. Maybe the default value for PHP 5 is different than it was for PHP 4? (Haven't checked)

Answer (score 1):

When the data is sent, is dependant on PHP configuration, it's an output buffer, and behaves like a buffer.

Having said that, you can use the function `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` to take control of the buffer. The Zend Framework does some clever stuff with output buffering for instance...

Answer (score 1):

The usual suspects are:

- Browser and HTML structure
- [Output buffering](http://es.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) or [output handlers](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-handler)
- HTTP compression handled by [PHP](http://es.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression) or by the [web server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html)

A close look at phpinfo() at a tool to see HTTP headers can help you.